# How to use specific hosted domain in identity provider google? Keycloak

Tags: google-oauth, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak with docker `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1` and with Google Identity provider.

According to the documentation I can use a property called `Hosted Domain` to restrict access to your GSuite organization's members only. [Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_google)

But when creating the provider, I don't see that column anywhere :/

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

This field is not on the google console, is [in the settings tab of Google Identity Provider Menu on Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOQqp.png)